# is it possible to have a computed property in enum (calling a function) by using a variable from another class?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, enums

I want to be able to set new values to an enum using information from another class.

I have tried to have the enum inside the class and call each property to give them new values, but enum's properties are read only. couldn't find a way to make it writable.
Then I had the enum in a separated file but then didn't know how to bring the value there and use it.

the variable connect to a HTTP client.

```
import {ClassVariable} from "...";

export enum myEnum {
 enum1=getValue("enum1"),
 . . . 
}

function getValue(text: string): number{
const classVariable: typeof ClassVariable; //error must be initialized
if(text==="enum1"){
  retun ClassVariable.getNumber();}
}
```

the code should be able to initialize the enum values

Comment: what does your `ClassVariable` contains or show the content here if it's an class

Comment: it gets some cached information

Comment: ok can you show the code for the same

Comment: For me, the point of enums that they are constant, so i would not make them volatile. Because then they would behave different to my expectations. Technicaly a typescript enum is a "normal" javascript class with public static attributes (only readonly), so you could also work with that. Then its also easy to change them. I only would work with get/set to make sure that no one can change your "constants" by mistake (using get only and change the content by a extra method)

Comment: you mean a code that ```ClassVariable``` works on?

Comment: so if I can call set, I can say ```myEnum.set??(classVariable.getNumber())```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums do not exist in Javascript.

In Typescript, [they're then compiled to objects](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAGlDeAoKUAeUC8UDkruIF8g).

Also, by definition, enums are constants. They shouldn't be set dynamically.

Considering all of that, you should simply use an Object, and call `Object.freeze()` when you're done setting it.